# TTS callback: dispatch completed to 1

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I created a small TTS app implementing OnUtteranceCompleteListener and, while things seem to be working exactly as expected, I noticed the following on LogCat (one for each completed utterance):

> 03-01 20:47:06.436:
>   VERBOSE/TtsService(381): TTS callback:
>   dispatch completed to 1

Again, this seems to be benign but I don't understand what '**1**' means. All such lines for all utterances say "completed to **1**", even for utterance IDs that are greater than 1.

What does '1' mean in this log?

BTW, this message is not generated by my code but rather by the TTS engine (Pico) itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [TTSService.java](http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn-history/r593/trunk/tts/src/com/google/tts/TTSService.java) source code available at http://eyes-free.googlecode.com you can find the function **dispatchUtteranceCompletedCallback()**:

```
private void dispatchUtteranceCompletedCallback(String utteranceId, String packageName) {
    /* Legacy support for TTS */
    final int oldN = mCallbacksOld.beginBroadcast();
    for (int i = 0; i < oldN; i++) {
        try {
            mCallbacksOld.getBroadcastItem(i).markReached("");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // The RemoteCallbackList will take care of removing
            // the dead object for us.
        }
    }
    try {
        mCallbacksOld.finishBroadcast();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // May get an illegal state exception here if there is only
        // one app running and it is trying to quit on completion.
        // This is the exact scenario triggered by MakeBagel
        return;
    }
    /* End of legacy support for TTS */
    ITtsCallbackBeta cb = mCallbacksMap.get(packageName);
    if (cb == null) {
        return;
    }
    Log.v(SERVICE_TAG, "TTS callback: dispatch started");
    // Broadcast to all clients the new value.
    final int N = mCallbacks.beginBroadcast();
    try {
        cb.utteranceCompleted(utteranceId);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // The RemoteCallbackList will take care of removing
        // the dead object for us.
    }
    mCallbacks.finishBroadcast();
    Log.v(SERVICE_TAG, "TTS callback: dispatch completed to " + N);
}
```

1 is the current value of N, which is initialized by the return value from **mCallbacks.beginBroadcast()**.

[beginBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RemoteCallbackList.html#beginBroadcast%28%29) is a method of the class [RemoteCallbackList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RemoteCallbackList.html) and its documentation states that it:

> Returns the number of callbacks in the
>   broadcast, to be used with
>   getBroadcastItem(int) to determine the
>   range of indices you can supply

Does this help?